# The deletion of iPhone application data from remote server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

1. What I am trying to do is when a user deletes data from server end & thus
   same data saved locally on mobile app should be deleted.
2. Scenario:

   Employee A is working in organisation & employee A is having
   organisation app & app data. When Employee A leaves the
   organisation, data from his organisation app can be deleted by
   organisation authority from server end without asking the Employee A.
3. The mechanism to do this might be
4. A. Manually check at regular interval from server whether the data
       exists on server side. The mechanism is inefficient.
5. B.  Push Notification: This looks good that whenever data is deleted
   from server end, push notification get fires and ask app to delete
   respected data.  The issue is user i.e Employee A may stop push
   notification of app.
6. C. Both A & B.

**Query:
So Please suggest what can be trusted & efficient way (A-C or any) to implement above scenario.**

Comment: Would a D. mechanism be acceptable? Why not simply check at app launch time or when it is woken up from sleep, if data needs to be deleted? You could design a specific API endpoint on the server end to allow that. Plus, that mechanism would also allow some kind of interaction with the user, to let him know that his data has Bern deleted.

Comment: Ok, I'll put it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check, at app launch time or when it is woken from sleep, if data needs to be deleted. You could design a specific API endpoint on the server end which would allow that. Plus, that mechanism would also allow some kind of interaction with the user, to let him know that his data has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait a bit with a hope to get any more options e,f g. Later i will mark this as a accepted answer.